# How to count the number of accounts related to a contact when multiple accounts to a contact is set

Tags: dlrs

I setup up multiple accounts to contact so I can't use rollup summary. I decided to use DLRS but in this case, the Account will have to act as the child object since the details will be summed up on the contact page. However, Account is the parent object. I do not know what relation ID, criteria, and relationship field to use because of this. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Allow Contacts to be related to multiple Accounts" feature gives you access to the `AccountContactRelation` SObject (ACR for short), which acts as a junction table.

ACR contains two master-detail relationship fields (one relating it to the Account, and another relating it to the contact), and Salesforce enforces a rule saying that each ACR must have a unique Contact-Account pair (i.e. a single Contact can't be related to the same Account twice, and a single Account can't be related to the same Contact twice).

So if you keep the Contact constant, then the number of Accounts it's related to is equal to the number of ACR records for that Contact.

Contact is the "parent" object, and you'd be summarizing the ACR object.